# When Adding ASP Code, Navigation goes away in mobile and Other scripts freeze on the page

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, asp-classic

When I don't have the ASP Code included in the page, Everything works perfect :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Customer Reviews</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello world!">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:400,300,700|Orbitron:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->

<!-- Import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/products.css">
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <link href= "css/ie.css" rel= "stylesheet" media= "all" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<style>
#imgThumbs {
overflow: hidden;
/*  margin: 20px auto;*/
width: 396px;
text-align: center;
margin-left:-50px;
}

.showImg {
width: 100px;
padding: 15px;
float:left;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#imgHolder {

text-align:center;
width: 100%;
}

.imgDescription {
color: #fff;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
margin-top: -105px;
margin-bottom: 85px;
font-size: 25px;
/*padding-left: 50px;*/
text-align:center;
}


.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }

.ProductInfo{
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
margin-top: 15px;
}
.color-textgreen {
color: rgb(0, 153, 51);
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- #include file="layout-header.asp" -->

<div class="wrapper-basic">

    <!-- Start -->

<section id="portfolio" class="page" style="padding-bottom:0px;">

<div class="container">

<div class="span4">
<center><img src="img/ProductAIO.jpeg"/></center>

</div>
<div class="span6" style="float:right;">

<div class="title" style="font-size:30px; margin-bottom:0px">TITLE</div>
<hr>
</div>

<div class="span6" style="float:right;">
<div class="ProductInfo">



<br>          
<p style="font-size:18px"><strong>Your Price:</strong><span class="color-textgreen"><strong> $1,259.00</strong></span><br>
</p>




<br>

<!--<h3> <strong><span class="color-text">Ship Date:</span></strong></h3>-->

<p>Stock Status: Call To Check<br></p>


<br>
<p>Components: Ship within 24-48 hours<br>
Laptops/Computers: 5-10 Business days</p>

</div>         
</div>



<br>
<!-- Start Tabs -->

                    <div class="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="tab1" class="current">OVERVIEW</li>
                            <li id="tab2">SPECIFICATIONS</li>
                            <li id="tab3">REVIEWS</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content-wrp">
                            <div id="tab1-content" class="tab-content active">
                                <p>Pellentesque est dolor, malesuada et ultrices eu, fringilla sed magna. Mauris neque turpis, faucibus et tempus quis, accumsan at nunc. Nam placerat tristique dolor non lobortis.</p>
                                <p>Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Donec vel enim purus, id viverra neque. Cras in velit ante, eget pellentesque sem. Duis tincidunt erat quam. Etiam placerat sapien elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab2-content" class="tab-content">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas neque diam, luctus at laoreet in, auctor ut tellus. Etiam enim lacus, ornare et tempor, rhoncus rhoncus sem.</p>
                                <p>In vitae ipsum ac neque aliquam rutrum ac in metus. Sed sed est tincidunt mauris mattis hendrerit. Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab3-content" class="tab-content">
                                <p>Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Donec vel enim purus, id viverra neque. Cras in velit ante, eget pellentesque sem. Duis tincidunt erat quam. Etiam placerat sapien elit.</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas neque diam, luctus at laoreet in, auctor ut tellus. Etiam enim lacus, ornare et tempor, rhoncus rhoncus sem.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Tabs -->           

</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER --> 
</section>



    <!-- End -->

    <!-- #include file="layout-footer.asp" -->

</body>

</html>
```

but when I DO add this ASP Code, Part of the mobile navigation dissapears and the tabs in the bottom won't work anymore. The javascript included in it freezes up. I know its the ASP code because without it , it works fine.

```
<!-- #include file="db.asp" -->

<%
sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE catalogID = " &     Replace(Trim(Request.QueryString("id")),"'","")
call openConn()
Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset") ' dont touch
rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
%>
<%
Response.Write "<form action=""" & Application("secureurl") & "/cart/view-cart.asp"" method=""POST""  name=""form"">"
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fproductid"" value=""" & rs("catalogID") & """>"' dont  touch
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fquantity"" value=""1"">" ' dont touch
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fcat"" value=""" & rs("ccategory") & """>"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Product Page </title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello world!">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<!-- Import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/products.css">

<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<link href= "css/ie.css" rel= "stylesheet" media= "all" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<style>
#imgThumbs {
    overflow: hidden;
  /*  margin: 20px auto;*/
    width: 396px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:-50px;
}

.showImg {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#imgHolder {

    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}

.imgDescription {
color: #fff;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
margin-top: -105px;
margin-bottom: 85px;
font-size: 25px;
/*padding-left: 50px;*/
text-align:center;
}

.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ProductInfo{
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
margin-top: 15px;
}
.color-textgreen {
color: rgb(0, 153, 51);
}

</style>

<body>

<!-- #include file="layout-header.asp" -->

<!-- Start -->  
<div class="wrapper-basic">

<section id="portfolio" class="page" style="padding-bottom:0px;">

<div class="container">

<div class="span4">
<center><img src="img/ProductAIO.jpeg"/></center>
</div>
 <!-- END OF SPAN 4 -->

<div class="span6" style="float:right;">
<div class="title" style="font-size:30px; margin-bottom:0px">TITLE</div>
<hr>
</div>

<div class="span6" style="float:right;">
<div class="ProductInfo">



<br>          
<p style="font-size:18px"><strong>Your Price:</strong><span class="color-textgreen"><strong> $1,259.00</strong></span><br>
</p>
<%
Response.Write "<button class=""btn"" TYPE=""btn"" style=""background-color: #42a92a;color: #fff;"" >ADD TO CART</button> </form>"
%>
<%
rs.close
set rs = nothing
call closeConn()
%>



<br>

<!--<h3> <strong><span class="color-text">Ship Date:</span></strong></h3>-->

<p>Stock Status: Call To Check<br>
</p>
<br>
<p>Components: Ship within 24-48 hours<br>
Laptops/Computers: 5-10 Business days</p>

</div>         
</div>



<br>
<br>
<!-- Start Tabs -->
<div class="tabs">
<ul>
<li id="tab1" class="current">OVERVIEW</li>
<li id="tab2">SPECIFICATIONS</li>
<li id="tab3">REVIEWS</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content-wrp">
<div id="tab1-content" class="tab-content active">
<p>Pellentesque est dolor, malesuada et ultrices eu, fringilla sed magna. Mauris neque turpis, faucibus et tempus quis, accumsan at nunc. Nam placerat tristique dolor non lobortis.</p>
<p>Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Donec vel enim purus, id viverra neque. Cras in velit ante, eget pellentesque sem. Duis tincidunt erat quam. Etiam placerat sapien elit.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2-content" class="tab-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas neque diam, luctus at laoreet in, auctor ut tellus. Etiam enim lacus, ornare et tempor, rhoncus rhoncus sem.</p>
<p>In vitae ipsum ac neque aliquam rutrum ac in metus. Sed sed est tincidunt mauris mattis hendrerit. Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab3-content" class="tab-content">
<p>Aliquam volutpat arcu et nibh mollis eleifend pharetra lorem scelerisque. Donec vel enim purus, id viverra neque. Cras in velit ante, eget pellentesque sem. Duis tincidunt erat quam. Etiam placerat sapien elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas neque diam, luctus at laoreet in, auctor ut tellus. Etiam enim lacus, ornare et tempor, rhoncus rhoncus sem.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Tabs -->           


</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER --> 

</section>
<!-- END OF SECTION --> 

 </div>        

        <!-- End -->

        <!-- #include file="layout-footer.asp" -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gosh, where to begin...  for starters, your html is in a shambles.  Your form tag and hidden fields should be located inside the body element, not outside your html page.  Have you tried looking at the html code generated on the client-side?  That would be a good start for you to see how screwed up it is.

Comment: @CMKanode Thank you for your response. Yes I know, All these pages are the exact same way. I am here to clean up the page from the last person mantaining. I just ran into this issue. The only client side attached to this page just has Database stuff. Nothing really related to the HTML that I see. I know its something with the scripts at the very top. When those are removed, it works fine, but without it, The button to go to the cart wouldn't function.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a complete answer, since I really don't know what is in your ASP include files.  If you look, the FORM tag outputted by the ASP has been moved into the body.  Otherwise, the HTML is broken.  I'm inclined to believe that there will be more broken parts.  That was to biggest problem that I saw relating to your HTML code.

I don't like posting an answer that is not complete, but it's too much to talk about in a comment field.

And, concatenating a SQL statement is bad news...  Please do some searches on SQL Injection attacks.

```
<!-- #include file="db.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><!-- header content removed to save space --></head>
<style>/* styles removed to save space */</style>
<body>
<!-- #include file="layout-header.asp" -->
<!-- Start -->  
<div class="wrapper-basic">
<section id="portfolio" class="page" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
<div class="container">
<div class="span4">
    <center><img src="img/ProductAIO.jpeg"/></center>
</div>
<!-- END OF SPAN 4 -->

<div class="span6" style="float:right;">
    <div class="title" style="font-size:30px; margin-bottom:0px">TITLE</div>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="span6" style="float:right;">
    <div class="ProductInfo">
        <br>
        <p style="font-size:18px">
            <strong>Your Price:</strong><span class="color-textgreen">
            <strong> $1,259.00</strong></span><br>
        </p>
<%
sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE catalogID = " _
    & Replace(Trim(Request.QueryString("id")),"'","")
call openConn()
Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("adodb.Recordset") ' dont touch
rs.Open sqlCustomer, dbc, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
Response.Write "<form action=""" & Application("secureurl") & "/cart/view-cart.asp"" method=""POST""  name=""form"">"
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fproductid"" value=""" & rs("catalogID") & """>"
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fquantity"" value=""1"">" ' dont touch
Response.Write "<input type=""hidden"" name=""fcat"" value=""" & rs("ccategory") & """>"
Response.Write "<button class=""btn"" TYPE=""btn"" style=""background-color: #42a92a;color: #fff;"" >ADD TO CART</button> </form>"

rs.close
set rs = nothing
call closeConn()
%>
<br>
<p>Stock Status: Call To Check<br></p>
<br>
<p>Components: Ship within 24-48 hours<br>
Laptops/Computers: 5-10 Business days</p>
</div>         
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!-- Start Tabs -->
<!-- removed for space -->
<!-- End Tabs -->           
</div>
<!-- END OF CONTAINER --> 
</section>
<!-- END OF SECTION --> 
</div>        
    <!-- End -->
    <!-- #include file="layout-footer.asp" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will definitely check that out. Thanks a lot for the feedback! @cm